# How can I hide a type alias?

Tags: rust

I have a type alias of the form:

```rust
type ReadableName = unreadable::path::to::a::module::that::is::meant::to::be::an::implementation::detail::anway::UglyName;
```

Is there any way I can instruct Rust to always use `ReadableName` for error messages instead of the ugly aliased name?

Comment: I don't think so, but I think it would be a reasonable feature to have. Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17164

Comment: The only option for this moment is to use newtype for that but it would be not suitable almost always.

Comment: Yes, newtype unfortunately doesn't do the trick in this case.